# How to get the maximum value of the item of a struct when you have an array?

Tags: julia

I have the following structure in Julia and I create an array with it.

```
julia>     struct myStruct
              a::Int
              b::Int
              c::String
           end

julia>     myArray = myStruct.(1:10,11:20,"ABC")
10-element Array{myStruct,1}:
 myStruct(1, 11, "ABC") 
 myStruct(2, 12, "ABC") 
 myStruct(3, 13, "ABC") 
 myStruct(4, 14, "ABC") 
 myStruct(5, 15, "ABC") 
 myStruct(6, 16, "ABC") 
 myStruct(7, 17, "ABC") 
 myStruct(8, 18, "ABC") 
 myStruct(9, 19, "ABC") 
 myStruct(10, 20, "ABC")
```

What shall I do in Julia to get the maximum value of `a`?

Is it recommended to first getting a 2 column array with the first two values of the struct and then use `findmax(my2colArray[:,1])` to find the maximum value?

I have three questions to understand how shall I do this:

1. If getting the array first is needed, how do I get efficiently that 2 column array?
2. If it is not needed, how would I get the maximum value of `a` directly from the array of structs?
3. The string will contain a maximum of 50 characters, and they will be ASCII (no UTF-8). Shall I fix the length of the string somehow to improve performance?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. Why do you want a 2-column array, if you are only interested in `a`? Can you clarify exactly what you need? Do you care about the values in `b`? Do you want the index as well as the value?

Comment: I want to get the whole struct once I have identified the maximum value of `a`. But several rows can share that value and then I need the `b` column. I shall had simplified further the question, as you mention is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get the max value of `a` is, as @fredrikekre writes:

```
maxval = maximum(x->x.a, arr)
```

Unfortunately, this does not give you the index of that value, which you also asked for in a comment.

Ideally, you could use `argmax` or `findmax` instead:

```
(maxval, maxind) = findmax(x->x.a, arr)  # <= This does not work!!
```

Currently, at version 1.2 of Julia, this does not work.

There may be some other clever solution, but my advice is to just write a loop yourself, it's easy and educational!

To address your questions:

0: (This was not a question) Remember to always name your types with UpperCamelCase: so `MyStruct`, not `myStruct`.

1. No, you don't need this, and it's not a good solution. (Also I don't know why you want a 2-column vector, when you only are looking for the max of `a`). But if you really want it anyway:

   `v = getproperty.(x, [:a :b])`
2. For max value, see the answer by @fredrikekre, for max index see below.
3. No, I don't think so.

Write your own loop to get the max index and value. It's easy and fun, and you learn to write your own fast Julia code:

```
function find_amax(arr::AbstractArray{MyStruct})
    isempty(arr) && ArgumentError("reducing over an empty collection is not allowed")
    maxind, maxval = firstindex(arr), first(arr).a
    for (i, x) in enumerate(arr)
        if x.a > maxval
            maxind, maxval = i, x.a
        end
    end
    return maxval, maxind
end
```

There is a small inefficiency in the code above, the first value and index of `x` is read twice. If you want even faster performance, you can figure out a way to avoid that.

As for performance, this loop is about as fast as `maximum(x->x.a, arr)`, and more than 60x as fast as building the 2-column matrix you asked for in question 1.

The main lesson is: You don't need to look for some clever "built-in" solution that you can plug your problem into. If you cannot quickly find one, just make your own, it will most likely be *faster*.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I am clearly biased towards finding built-in operations rather than building loops.

Comment: If you want to use the second column as a tie-breaker, that's all the more reason to write your own custom loop :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `maximum` function. `maximum` also takes a function, which you, in this case, can use to sort by the `a` field:

```
julia> struct myStruct
           a::Int
           b::Int
           c::String
       end

julia> myArray = myStruct.(21:30,11:20,"ABC");

julia> val = maximum(x -> x.a, myArray)
30
```

(Slightly modified your example to make the maximum value and the index different).

Comment: `maximum` returns the maximum _value_ not its index. And, unfortunately, `argmax` and `findmax` do not currently (version 1.2) support passing a function as a first argument.

Comment: The idea would be to get the index, not the actual value. So you can retrieve the other values from the struct (this is a simplified example to make the question/answer easy to follow). Also I would like to know if I shall define the length/size of the String.

Comment: @M.E. Can you update your question to clarify that you are looking for the index? Right now, your question only asks for the max value.

Comment: Ah, right of course. Tricky example when the value and index are the same. Edited the post.

Comment: Yes in this case it is a bit tricky because it is the same number (figure and value)